How to hide EmailMessage from shared users?
Say I have an Account that I share with user A and B.
If user A sends email message, I don't want user B to see it.
So far I found Email Messages appear as Task object. TaskShare object doesn't seem to exist and my ideas ran out around here...

How about avoid logging emails in Salesforce then?

@RenatoOliveira example was in EmailMessage but it's valid concept for all types of Tasks/Activities.

I was able to achieve this using relatively new feature - Restriction Rules.
I've created rule on Task object with
User Criteria
$User.IsActive=true
Record Criteria
 Owner:User.Id=$User.Id
Edit: This doesn't work when you enable Enhanced Email which then creates EmailMessage AND Task (without it only creates Task). I need to reconsider this approach...

Is the "user is active = true" criteria an analogy for "1 = 1" in SQL? Is it in there just so you can create the rule because that field is mandatory?

Correct. IIRC you need values in both. And while they say to design the rules in the way that only one "applies" - in my case it worked correctly.

Tasks are a type of activity. So the object which you are trying to control access would be Activity
I think the use case in question is not possible to achieve since any user with Read access to the record will be able to at least view the related 'activity' i.e. EmailMessage.
Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5
In the above article, Activity Access Levels sub-header has details about the possible OWD settings for Activity object.
Edit : As per the comment from @dzh, this can be achieved using Restriction rules.

Restriction Rules seems to be way to go. I've followed this explanation and turns out IdeaExchange ideas were delivered!

Great. I was not aware about this feature. Thank you !
